# PySide QEvent post crash

Tags: pyside

I’m working on Linux Ubuntu 12.10, with PySide 1.1.1 and python 2.7
 I have a problem when posting QEvent through a QStateMachine.

If I want it to work I have to keep a reference on the event, or it crashes.
 I have set up a little sample code to illustrate my problem.

I would like to know if I am doing it wrong or if it is a known problem and if I should use the workaround (keeping a reference on the event) ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
sm = QStateMachine()
init = QState(sm)
sm.setInitialState(init)
sm.start()

e = None
def no_crash():
    global e
    print("send an event that doesn't crash...")
    e = QEvent(QEvent.Type(QEvent.registerEventType()))
    sm.postEvent(e)

def crash():
    print("and one that does...")
    e = QEvent(QEvent.Type(QEvent.registerEventType()))
    sm.postEvent(e)

QTimer.singleShot(2000, no_crash)
QTimer.singleShot(4000, crash)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks by advance for your help

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bug in PySide.

What I see when I run your example is a crash because of a double free. Probably the underlying C++ event object is destroyed once when when the python event object goes out of scope, and once when the event is deleted by the StateMachine, as the [documentation](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QStateMachine.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QStateMachine.postEvent) says:

> The state machine takes ownership of the event and deletes it once it has been processed.

If the StateMachine takes onwnership of the event, you shouldn't need to keep a reference.

It would be best to file a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/).

The same code doesn't crash with `PyQt4`.